# Combining Code First tables and existing tables in one context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have several tables in my SQL database that are generated from POCO objects using Code First and Migrations. I also have several tables in a different Schema that are created outside of the project by another process.

How would I combine these two sets of tables in one DB Context without losing the code first migrations features and without overwriting the existing tables in the second Schema?

Comment: Are you insistent on having them in one DbContext?  Or are you okay with have two DbContext's in the same project/assembly?

Comment: I have them in two DbContexts but was hoping to simplify things by putting them in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple actually. Create or reverse engineer the other schema POCOs. Add any fluent config needed (or get it from reverse engineered class)

```
public virtual DbSet<OtherSchemaTable> OtherSchemaTable {get; set; }'
...
```

Create a new migration to replace your snapshot, but not update the database:

```
add-migration OtherSchemaAdded -IgnoreChanges
update-database
```

Now you can continue on with migrations for your tables and reference the other schema. As long as you don't change other schema models you are OK. If you are worried about that, another option is to use database views to reference the other schema tables (assuming no updates needed).

Comment: Can a single dbcontext span multiple databases/schema?

Comment: Sure. Either add an attribute above the class like [Table(Name = "foo", Schema = "mySchema")] or use fluent api .ToTable("foo", schemaName: "mySchema")  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.3

Comment: What happens when both sets of tables have to evolve? Maintaining the ordering of migration operations can get very tricky and snapshot sizes grow...

Comment: For the tables you control, keep using migrations. If tables you don't control change, simply repeat the process of reverse engineer and running an -IgnoreChanges migration. At some point you may even want to consolidate or roll up your migrations as Chris Pratt describes here: http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=54ad5c7b61c48943&at_ab=per-12&at_pos=0&at_tot=1

Answer (score 0):

That means you have to take over the migrations process.  I am not sure the EF team currently supports exempting certain entities from the Migration process (at least not directly). Perhaps you can the entities in question with a custom Attribute that you define.  Then override the default SqlGenerator to ignore entities with this Attribute so CREATE TABLE statements are not issued for them.